# Unexplained spike in Affiliate conversions

Tags: google-analytics, conversions, affiliate, web-traffic

I've been seeing a massive conversion spike in affiliate sales (Pepperjam single advertiser). But no change in traffic. I'll show three months below, but I could just as easily go back years and the graphs would look basically the same. The changes aren't for a single affiliate link either, all links increased conversion (from what I can tell with small sample size).

**Conversion Spike**

[image: Conversion Spike]

But notice no change in the click throughs. (Also, no major change in traffic on our website - in fact down about 1%)

**Flat Click Throughs**

[image: Clicks are flat]

My question is 2 fold :

> 1) What is the most likely reason behind this kind of spike? 20% conversion rate seems pretty crazy (not that i'm complaining :)
>
> 2) What can I do to identify which clicks are converting? (I'm new to Google Analytics so maybe it has some report that would throw some light on the problem)